# Matrix functions, ODEs

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm struggling to solve this exrcise:
Given $$ \dot{\bf{x}} = A\bf{x}, A = \begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & -1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & -1
\end{bmatrix}$$
I need to find the expression for $\bf{x}(t)$ as a function of $\bf{x}(0)$ and determine whether a solution (or more) s.t. $\bf{x}(t) \to \infty$ as $ t \to \infty$ exists.
Now I used the standard approach. Since $A$ is symmetric and its coefficients belong to $\mathbb{R}$, it is therefore diagonalizable, namely, there exists a diagonal matrix $D$, whose entries are the eigenvalues of $A$ s.t. the following is true $$ A = PDP^{-1}, D = P^{-1}AP$$, where $P$ is the matrix whose columns are represented by the eigenvectors of $A$.
Now I know that a solution for my ODE is the following:
$$\bf{x}(t) = e^{tA}\bf{x}(0), e^{tA} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{t^nA^n}{n!} $$
Now I can rewrite like this: $$e^{tA} =  \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{t^nA^n}{n!} = P\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(tD)^n}{n!}P^{-1} = P e^{tD}P^{-1}$$
Now I computed the eigenvalues and eigenvecotrs and the  $P$ matrix obtaining:
$$ \lambda_{i \in [1,3]} = \{-1,2,-2\} , \bf{v_1} = [-1,1,1]^{T}, \bf{v_2} = [2,1,1]^T, \bf{v_3} =[0,1,-1]^T$$
$$P = \begin{bmatrix} 
-1 & 2 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & -1
\end{bmatrix}, D =  \begin{bmatrix} 
-1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -2
\end{bmatrix}$$
Now since $D$ is diagonal it's easy to see that $e^{tD} = \begin{bmatrix} 
e^{-t} & 0 & 0 \\
0 & e^{2t} & 0 \\
0 & 0 & e^{-2t}
\end{bmatrix} $
Now if I compute the triple product in order to obtain $e^{tA}$ I end up with a hideous $3 \times 3$, which I will not copy here. I was a bit skeptical about this procedure, therefore I decided to check out the solution given by my Professor, and what I get is this:
*Since $A$ is self-adjoint, its eigenvectors are all real and taken any two pair of

eigenvectors of $A$ are orthogonal, the solution is $$\bf{x}(t) = \sum_{n=1}^{3}a_n\bf{v}_ne^{\lambda_n t} $$, where the coefficients $a_i$ can be determined from the initial solution*
Now this was a little bit unsettling:
After reading this, I thougth maybe I should express $\bf{x}(0)$ as a linear combination of the eigenvectors, thus obtaining:
$$\bf{x}(0) = \sum_{i = 1}^{3} a_i \bf{v}_i $$ thereby getting:
$$ \bf{x}(t) = e^{tA}\bf{x}(0) = a_1e^{tA}\bf{v_1} + a_2e^{tA}\bf{v}_2 + a_3e^{tA}\bf{v}_3$$
The problem is now evident:
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{3}a_n\bf{v}_ne^{\lambda_n t}  \ne e^{tA}\bf{x}(0) = a_1e^{tA}\bf{v_1} + a_2e^{tA}\bf{v}_2 + a_3e^{tA}\bf{v}_3$$, or equivalently, how can the following two be equivalent:
$$  \sum_{i=1}^{3}a_i f(\lambda_i)v_i \equiv  \sum_{i=1}^{3}a_if(A)v_i  $$
Can someone tell me where I'm doing wrong, I followed the standard brute-force method that worked other times too, but this time it seems to fail? How could this happen?
Or is the solution wrong(I highly doubt it, but we never know)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to solve the 3x3 system - The behavior of the solution as $t \rightarrow \infty$ is determined by the coefficients ${a_1, a_2, a_3}$.

The solution goes to infinity as long as $a_2 \ge 0$, since the other components tend to $0$, and $v_2$ has positive elements in all of it's components. That's all.

Regarding your second question, the equality is in fact correct (although may not be intuitive). One way to look at it is by going back to the definition of an exponent of a matrix -

$e^A = \sum A^n/n!$

If you write $A=PDP^t$, where $PP^t=I$, you get that

$e^A = P (\sum D^n/n!) P^t $

Since $D$ is diagonal, the middle matrix is simply a diagonal matrix with the exponents of the eigenvalues on it's diagonal.

Thus, $ e^A v_i = P (\sum D^n/n!) P^t v_i = e^\lambda v_i$ , which gives the equality you presented.

Comment: Wait I know that $e^{tA} $ is diagonal if $A$ is diagonal, nevertheless the matrix we're interested in is the product between three matrices, the middle one is diagonal, but the triple product isn't. Furthermore, when you multiply a diagonal matrix by a vector in $\mathbb{R}^3$,you just need to multiply the three components of your vector (x_1,x_2,x_3) by the elements of the diagonal. You would then get $[a_{11}x_1,...] $. But somehow in the solution the first eigenvector is multiplied by the exponential of its corresponding eigenvalue, and so for the others. How could you get such a result?

Comment: What I wrote could be right. An example is shown here https://sites.millersville.edu/bikenaga/linear-algebra/matrix-exponential/matrix-exponential.html   there is also everything we talked about.  it basically shows that the equality above can't be true. Unless I'm missing something evident, which is highly likely. Let me know if agree with me and what I stated in my previous message

Comment: another question: in your last equality you express $A = P\sum_n D^n/n!$ when we instead put ourselves in a basis where $A$ is diagonal, so why don't we keep working in this basis (the base formed by the eigenvectors of our initial matrix)? We diagonalized $A$ obtaining $D$ so that $e^{tA}$ would also be diagonal with respect to this peculiar basis, but somehow we don't seem to use this advantage

Comment: Yes, you can think of it as a change of basis (geometrically), but I think the algebraic point of view is also important to understand. If follows from the known lemma that if $A=P^tDP$ and $PP^t=I$, then $A^n=P^tD^nP$. Substitute this in the power series of the matrix exponent and you'll get the result above.

Answer (score 0):

The following solution was given to me by my friend @Matteo Menghini.

Basically after diagonalizing our matrix, we notice that $A$, being a real symmetric matrix, is also self-adjoint. Therefore the three eigenvectors form an orthogonal basis. By normalizing them we get an orthonormal basis $\mathbb{B} = \{\bf{u_1}, u_2, u_3\}, u_i = \frac{\bf{v_i}}{||\bf{v_i}||}$
Now using the spectral decomposition we obtain:
$$ A = \sum_{i=1}^{3}\lambda_iP_i$$, where $P_i$ denotes the operator projection onto the unitary vector $\bf{u_i}$.
Hence we get
$$\bf{x}(t) = e^{tA}\bf{x}(0) = [e^{\lambda_1t}P_1+ e^{\lambda_2t}P_2 + e^{\lambda_3t}P_3]x(0) = e^{\lambda_1t}x_1u_1+ e^{\lambda_2t}x_2u_2 + e^{\lambda_2t}x_3u_3$$
where $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ are the components of $\bf{x}(0)$ with respect to our orthonormal basis

Comment: That is also correct, but I think misses the point. There's nothing to do with orthonormality here, and if $A$ wasn't orthogonally diagonalizable the claim stays the same exactly. It is important for you to understand the solution above as well.

Comment: @Amit, I'm not trying to be annoying, I'll post my calculations so that you can observe that I did as you told me and got a different result: $$ e^{A} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{PD^nP^{-1}}{n!} = P \sum_{n}\left(D^n/n!\right) P^{-1}$$

Comment: now I compute the diagonal matrix exponential like this: \ $$ P\begin{bmatrix} \sum_{n}\frac{\lambda_1^n}{n!} & 0& 0 \\  0 & \sum_{n}\frac{\lambda_2^n}{n!} & 0 \\ 0 & 0 &  \sum_{n}\frac{\lambda_3^n}{n!} \end{bmatrix}  P^{-1}= P  \begin{bmatrix} e^{\lambda_1} & 0& 0 \\  0 & e^{\lambda_2} & 0 \\ 0 & 0 &  e^{\lambda_3} \end{bmatrix}P^{-1}$$ Now let's set $\bf{v_i} = [x_1,x_2,x_3]^T$. We, therefore, end up with   $$ e^{A}v_i = [e^{\lambda_1}x_1, e^{\lambda_2}x_2, e^{\lambda_3}x_3]^T \ne e^{\lambda}\bf{v_i} $$

Comment: Tell me if it's the same result that you wanted me to obtain, and correct me if you find any of my computations to be wrong.

Comment: I don't understand how you computed $e^av_i$, it looks like you simply multiplied it by $D$ and forgot about the other two matrices. You know that $v_i$ are the columns of $P$, therefore $P^{-1}v_i=e_i$ the i-th unit vector, and thus $$PDP^{-1}v_i = PDe_i = Pe^{\lambda_i e_i} = e^{\lambda_i}v_i $$ exactly as I explained earlier.

Comment: I thought I could do this $$P^{-1}PDP^{-1}Pv_i$$ and forget about the two matrices. But I was wrong. Now it all makes sense. Now I had to compute the product $P^{-1}v_i$ manually in order for me to verify the relation $P^{-1}v_i = e_i$. Did you happen to already know this result? I can't see an easy way of seeing this beforehand without going straight for computations. Anyways, thanks for your patience and availability, you've been of great help!

Comment: It's an elementary relation in linear algebra you should be aware of, and may help with future exercises as well!

The main idea is that if $A=[A_1,...,A_n]$ is a matrix with $A_i$ as it's columns, then $Ae_i = A_i$ (easily verified via matrix multiplication), and thus, if $A$ is inertible, then $e_i = A^{-1}A_i$, which is what I used in my computation.

Comment: Thanks @Amit, I'll make good use of it for sure, I also accepted your answer